# Show a Toast if the value exists in ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a problem with an `ArrayList`, so i want to check `ArrayList` and compare it with a value from `TextView` and show a `Toast` if the value  from `TextView` is already exist.

Here is some code that I've already tried:

**Code 1**

```
TextView namamenu=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nama_menu2);
EditText jumlahmenu=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtJumlahMenu);
MenuInputClass sr = new MenuInputClass();
String hehe = namamenu.getText().toString();
String hihi = jumlahmenu.getText().toString();
sr.setNama_menu(hehe);
sr.setJumlah_menu(hihi);

//results is the arraylist
if(results.contains(hehe)) {
    Toast.makeText(Appetizer_Activity.this, "already exist"+hehe, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**Code 2:**

```
if(results.contains(sr)) {
    Toast.makeText(Appetizer_Activity.this, "already exist"+hehe, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**my PemesananMenuClass :**
    public class PemesananMenuClass extends Application {

```
    private static String nama_menu;
    private String harga_menu;
    private String keterangan_menu;
    private String gambar;

     public void setNama_menu(String nama_menu) {
       PemesananMenuClass.nama_menu=nama_menu;
     }

    public String getNama_menu() {
        return (nama_menu);
    }
    actually there are some other artibute
```

**my ListPemesananActivity class :**

```
public class ListPemesanan_Activity extends Activity {


        Button submit_list_pemesanan,submit_reservasi_nomeja;
        TextView cobacoba;                 
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        //public static ArrayList<MenuInputClass> searchResults = GetSearchResults();
        public static ListView list_pemesanan;
        protected static ListView lv;      

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_pemesanan_menu);

    //  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);
        // lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        submit_list_pemesanan=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_submit_list_pemesanan);
        submit_reservasi_nomeja=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_reservasi_meja);
        list_pemesanan=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        //final TextView tnamamenu = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtNamaMasuk);
        //EditText tnomeja = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNoMeja);
        //final TextView tjumlahmenu = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtJumlahMasuk);

        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            for (int i = 0; i < list_pemesanan.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                                View viewListPemesanan = list_pemesanan.getChildAt(i);
                                TextView txtNamaMenu = (TextView) viewListPemesanan.findViewById(R.id.txtNamaMasuk);
                                TextView txtJumlahMenu = (TextView) viewListPemesanan.findViewById(R.id.txtJumlahMasuk);
                                EditText txtNoMeja = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNoMeja);
                                String masuk_namamenu = txtNamaMenu.getText().toString();
                                String masuk_jumlahmenu = txtJumlahMenu.getText().toString();
                                String masuk_nomeja = txtNoMeja.getText().toString();
                               // Toast.makeText(ListPemesanan_Activity.this, ""+cacad, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
                                initializeData(masuk_namamenu,masuk_jumlahmenu,masuk_nomeja);
                            }                              
                       }

                        private void initializeData(String masuk_namamenu,String masuk_jumlahmenu,String masuk_nomeja) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                             ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
                                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nama_menu",masuk_namamenu));
                                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jumlah",masuk_jumlahmenu));
                                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("no_meja",masuk_nomeja));
                                sendData(nameValuePairs);   
                        }

                        private void sendData(ArrayList<NameValuePair> data) {
                                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                  // 1) Connect via HTTP. 2) Encode data. 3) Send data.
                                 try
                                 {
                                     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://nervousme.vacau.com/android/insert_pesanan_new.php");
                                     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
                                     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                                 }
                                 catch(Exception e)
                                 {
                                     Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
                                 } 
                        }
                }; 
        submit_list_pemesanan.setOnClickListener(listener);    

        OnClickListener listener1 = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    EditText txtNoMeja = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNoMeja);

                    String masuk_nomeja = txtNoMeja.getText().toString();
                   // Toast.makeText(ListPemesanan_Activity.this, ""+cacad, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
                    initializeData(masuk_nomeja);

           }

            private void initializeData(String masuk_nomeja) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);                 
                     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("no_meja",masuk_nomeja));
                    sendData(nameValuePairs);   
            }

            private void sendData(ArrayList<NameValuePair>   data) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      // 1) Connect via HTTP. 2) Encode data. 3) Send data.
                     try
                     {
                         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://nervousme.vacau.com/android/reservasi_nomeja.php");
                         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
                         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                     }
                     catch(Exception e)
                     {
                         Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
                     } 
            }
    };
```

Any idea on why the toast doesn't appear?

Comment: Did you check what values are present in the results array list? Does it contain the string value represented by hehe?

Comment: @Neo  i want to check if results contains with hehe or not and if results contains hehe, the toast appear..thanks.did i made a mistake in this post?

Comment: It looks like the "results" arraylist is being generated elsewhere (on a server maybe?). I was asking about what elements are present in this arraylist? Because in code 1 you are comparing it with a string, and in code 2 you are comparing it with something totally different (a MenuInputClass object). Can you print/log them out before you make the comparison? You can use Log.v("MYTAG", "results" + results);

Comment: @Neo
the results arraylist being generated by ListPemesananActivity..this is the log, iam inserting the same name :'11-09 08:56:40.931: V/MYTAG(14930): results[kelas.MenuInputClass@40676340, kelas.MenuInputClass@40682530, kelas.MenuInputClass@4068df30, kelas.MenuInputClass@406997e8, kelas.MenuInputClass@406a5280]' thanks..

Comment: You have to learn how to write better questions. Please read this page at least once! http://sscce.org/

What is a MenuInputClass? What is a "ListPemesananActivity"?? I had to look at your other questions to find out.. And nobody usually does that. 

[For reference for other people - the other question I was referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028640/add-data-to-listview-redudancy-overwrite-android]

Comment: iam sorry, i thought to solve my problem, its just need some that above code..thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arraylist contains MenuInputClass objects, and you have to traverse the list to find out if any object contains the strings that you need. Depending on if you want your Toast notification to appear once or multiple times, you might want to break from the loop.

You can try doing something like this.

```
for(MenuInputClass mic : results) {
    if(mic.getNama_menu().equals(hehe)) {
        Toast.makeText(Appetizer_Activity.this, "already exist"+hehe, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Uncomment the line below if you want Toast to show notifications once FOR EVERY appearance of the string
        // break;
    } else if (mic.getJumlha_menu().equals(hihi)) {
        Toast.makeText(Appetizer_Activity.this, "already exist"+hihi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Uncomment the line below if you want Toast to show notifications once FOR EVERY appearance of the string
        // break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks its work..sorry for many mistakes that make you confuse..i'll learn it..and i really appreciate your help...

Answer (score 0):

In the first example (`if(results.contains(hehe))`) you are asking if the `hehe` object is in the array list, NOT if any of the objects in the array list has the same text as `hehe`.  You can have two `String`s that contain the exact same set of characters but they are different objects.

If your goal is to determine if any of the entries in the array list contain the same text, you need to compare the text that each of the objects contain.  E.g.,

```
for (String myString : results) {
    if (myString.compare(hehe)) {
        Toast.makeText(Appetizer_Activity.this, "already exist"+hehe, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          
        break;
    }
]
```

Comment: hi..if i insert 1st data, its works normal then i insert 2nd different data but the toast appeared..example :1st data = rice,2nd data = water, after inserting water, the toast appeared..i changed _String myString : results_ to _MenuInputClass myString : results_ and .compare is undefined method so i changed it to contains..thanks